# Why are my Lightroom-exported images very small, like 300-400 KB?

Tags: lightroom, export

[image]My RAW files are 25 MB, but when I process them in Lightroom and export them, they become only 300-400 KB, which is not acceptable by shutter stock and other image selling platforms.

Comment: Something is wrong with your export settings. Please, put a screen capture of them.

Comment: I wouldn't call 300-400KB small... and why do you think because it's no longer 25MB it's bad.. I would highly doubt image selling platforms have a min file size validation...

Comment: Did you crop the image?

Comment: 1600x2400 is only 3.8 megapixels. The original raw is probably 24MP. Don't resize the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why image's are very small like 300-400kb after export from Lightroom?

Judging by your screenshot, it's because you're resizing them and exporting them as a JPEG file. Those 25MB files you have are probably RAW files straight from the camera.

Comment: That's all I know, what's the solution.

Comment: @AtulAgarawal What's the problem? Do you want to export to a format that doesn't use lossy compression? Choose a format like PNG. Do you want to keep the full resolution of the image? Uncheck *Resize to fit*. The fact that your files are smaller when you export them isn't a problem in itself; if you're unhappy with the exported files for some reason, then look to change that aspect of the files when you export them.

Answer (score 5):

You have the **Resize to Fit** option checked in the **Image Sizing** section. This is going to resize the image, making it smaller. If your RAW file is 25MB, it must be about 20mp, or approximately 5790px in width, and you have the limit of 2400px set.

If you're exporting for stock photo, I'm guessing you want full size, so just *uncheck* the **Resize to Fit** option.

Comment: This is the better answer. Too bad the other is selected.